# Is there a Status Machine Chart?

Tags: time-series, quality-control

I find this type of chart quite often, but I don't know if it is known by another specific name:

[image: Status Machine Chart]

It looks like a 100% stacked bar chart, but colors repeat and it is actually different.

It may be implemented with Gantt, but it still looks like a way too complex hack.

What do you know about it and how can we easily emulate it with other more common chart types?

Answer (score 2):

It's three [time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series), each plotting the status of a single machine over time.  Instead of the value of each of the three series being indicated by a y-coordinate, it is indicated by one of three colors (as there are only three possible values of the machine status).

Note that the choice of colors is not good: many humans possess a visual system that does not distinguish well between red and green wavelengths of light.  Images that convey information with color should always take this into account.  I recommend downloading an application that simulates color impairment.

Comment: thanks, but not really helpfull. yes, it's clearly multi-series, each line is for a different machine. it's time series because the x axis shows ... time. it may have 3 or ...10 color, whatever, the point is same color may repeat itself on the same line, unlike for stack bars. question was how is it recognized by chart apps, and what standard chart types can we use to better emulate it.

Comment: The mostly negative comment above was ignored for good reason. If the real question was about implementing the graph in some unstated software, then that was (1) off-topic (2) not clear any way.